# Batch lowercase of text files content

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-16, lowercase

After half an hour searching for an answer to this, I can't think of a way to do it (without it involving opening each text file individually, selecting all and then lowercase-ing with gedit. I would like to be able to run a script, be it by commandline or preferably to include into nautilus-scripts, so that if I select the files on the GUI and rightclick to scripts and lowercase and it will be done.
 I know that tr is able to know how to do it, but I can't figure out how can I turn the following call to  `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < input.txt > output.txt` Normally, I would change input.txt to *.txt and *.txt for output.txt, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Extra: once that is solved, how to adapt it for nautilus-scripts? :]

Thanks!

Comment: Might be better served at [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com)

Comment: I don't get the askubutu.com comment. @jlo, consider modifying your post to indicate what is the typical extension used for 'nautilus-scripts'? Good luck.

Comment: Like @shellter, I don't know what nautilus-scripts requires, so if you can explain the requirements for making it work with nautilus-scripts then you're more likely to get a helpful answer to that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
This turned out to be an encoding issue - the OP's input files are UTF16.

After a discussion in the comments, the OP copy/pasted the data from viewing with `less` into a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/uHmYmhpT

It looked like this:

```
<FF><FE>1^@^M^@
^@0^@0^@:^@0^@0^@:^@0^@9^@,^@4^@4^@2^@ ^@-^@-^@>^@ ^@0^@0^@:^@0^@0^@:^@1^@1^@,^@4^@4^@4^@^M^@
^@j& ^@W^@O^@K^@E^@ ^@U^@P^@^M^@
^@T^@H^@I^@S^@ ^@M^@O^@R^@N^@I^@N^@G^@ ^@j&^M^@
^@^M^@
^@2^@^M^@
```

... and so on.

This is clearly not an ascii (or utf8) text file, and so most standard tools (`sed`, `grep`, `awk`, etc) will not work on it.

The `<FF><FE>` at the start is a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that indicates that this file is UTF16-encoded text. There is a standard tool for converting between UTF16 and UTF8, and UTF8 is compatible with ascii for alphanumeric characters so if we convert it to UTF8, then `sed`/`grep`/`awk`/etc will be able to edit it.

The tool we need is `iconv`. Unfortunately, `iconv` has no in-place editing feature so we'll have to write a loop that uses a temporary file to do the conversion:

```
find . -type f -name '*.srt' -print0 | while read  -d '' filename; do
    if file "$filename"|grep -q 'UTF-16 Unicode'; then
        iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF8 -o "$filename".utf8 "$filename" && mv "$filename".utf8 "$filename"
    fi
done
```

Then you can run the `find`/`sed` command to lowercase them. Most programs won't care that your files are now UTF8 rather than UTF16, but if you have issues then you can write a similar loop that uses `iconv` to put them back into UTF16 after you've lowercased them.

---

If you just want to lowercase all files matching '*.txt':

```
sed -i 's/.*/\L&/' *.txt
```

But note that this will run into issues with the command line length if there's a lot of .txt files.

If you want to do lowercasing on all files recursively, I'd use Diego's approach - but there's a couple of errors to fix:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/.*/\L&/' {} +
```

should do the trick.

If you *don't* want it to be recursive, you want it to only affect '`.txt`' files, and you've got too many files for the `sed ... *.txt` to work, then use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i 's/.*/\L&/' {} +
```

(`-maxdepth 1` stops the recursion)

Older versions of find won't support the `-exec ... +` syntax, so if you run into trouble with that then replace the `+` with `\;`. The `+` is preferable because it makes `find` invoke `sed` with multiple files per invocation, rather than once per file, so it's slightly more efficient.

Comment: None of those suggestions worked. The files are '.srt', instead of txt, but even changing those parts in the commands you wrote, no effect took place.

Comment: @jlo that's very odd... did they have any effect at all, or did you get any errors?

Comment: With "sed -i 's/.*/\L&/' *.srt", it executed without any errors. I even had one file open and gedit informed me that the content had changed. I reloaded/opened other files though and nothing changed.
I uploaded to pastebin (here: http://pastebin.com/3ib9ziAB) a part of the file, so maybe you can try it out on your machine?

Comment: it works on that file for me - it sounds very much like something about how you're running it rather than the command itself. If your files aren't all in the same dir, then `cd` to the dir that has all your srt files under it and use: `find . -type f -name '*.srt' -exec sed -i 's/.*/\L&/' {} \;`

Comment: I'm certainly intrigued as well. I successfully cd to where the *.srt are. I execute that command and it takes a couple of seconds (12 files or so) and then it's back to prompt. I would think that it's due to the fact of not having the "sed" function installed, but if that were the case, it would give out an error/warning, right? Is there a way to find out manually if sed is installed properly?

Comment: @jlo what do you get if you just run `find . -type f -name '*.srt'`? It should print the list of files you want to be lowercased

Comment: And yes, you should get a warning if sed can't be found/run. If you want to test the sed by itself, just run `sed -i 's/.*/\L&/' whatever.srt`  and see if whatever.srt changes.

Comment: that find command prints the list of *.srt's in the folder successfully. The second command (sed and whatever.srt) doesn't change the whatever,srt, Got more ideas? I get the feeling something is wrong with my sed version.

Comment: @jlo sounds like it, yeah. Are you on Linux, or unix/bsd/macos/cygwin? can you get "sed -i" to do any in place changes? do you have write permission on the file and the directory it's in?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 11.04. The funny thing is, I just tried at work with 10.04 LTS and it works!!! How can I check if I have writting permission in the directory it's in back home? Do you think sudo-ing the sed command would do it? Thanks for all the awesome feedback, btw :)

Comment: well if I were you I'd make sure it works without sudo because needeing root isn't good... but if it doesn't even work with sudo, something's really screwed up. Use `ls -l /path/to/srts/whatever.srt` and `ls -ld /path/to/srts` to view the permissions. see http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html for how to interpret them.

Comment: I have read and write permission over the file and Im also the owned of it (checked with the link and the ls commands). Any further last resorts you can think of?

Comment: 1) try it with sudo, 2) `cd` to wherever your srts are and run this lot of commands and put it on a pastebin: `ls -ld . whatever.srt`; `lsattr -ld . whatever.srt`; `df .`; `mount`; `cat /proc/mounts`; 3) Check that the files really haven't been modified by running `less whatever.srt` from the same shell you ran sed on (i.e. no gui apps, and don't use a different window for sed-ing vs checking).

Comment: With the sudo it didnt work either. Here you go: http://pastebin.com/XXVBztMx and here is all the weird stuff I see where I open it with less (I also get asked by less prior to opening if im sure, that it can be a binary file): http://pastebin.com/uHmYmhpT

Comment: Ah, finally we get to the bottom of the issue! I'll update the answer to explain..

Comment: Dude, you are the best: it worked. Thanks for all the help you've given me in these answers. It's been great. Now I just have to read up on regular expressions to find out and understand the command Im using with sed to do the lowercase. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it, but I think this would work to search recursively through directories, looking in all the files, and replacing their contents for their lowercase version:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i ‘s/.+/\0\L/’ {} \;
```

Comment: Added my answer below because this has a couple of issues that stop it from actually working, even though it's the right approach. The two issues: `+` doesn't work without `sed -r` (extended regex syntax), and the `\L` needs to precede the `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a short script to transform files of the form "*.txt" to "*-lowered.txt":

```
#!/bin/bash
# lowerit.sh
in=$1
out=${in/.txt/-lowered.txt}
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < $in > $out
```

If you want to transform multiple files, you can't use output.txt for all of them, of course. And you cant write to the input file - this will truncate it.

You can write to an intermediate file, and rename it as second step in the end.

To handle multiple files, use find:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec ./lowerit.sh {} +
```